# Registering for significant-change location versus startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy:

Tags: ios

Registering for significant change location the app only receives coarse location updates (if the device moves from cell to cell), however according to this post

[If background applications can't launch automatically how does Cardcase launch on a location change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674214/if-background-applications-cant-launch-automatically-how-does-cardcase-launch-o)

its also possible to use startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy: and have the app woken up when a location change occurs.

Presumably the desiredAccuracy can be pretty fine, so does this imply its a back-door way of registering for significant changes to location but with a fine grain?
Is it permissable by the app store therefore?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not really. You have to specify a specific region, and you only get sent notifications when the region is entered/exited.

It's the same mechanism that the Reminders app uses for sending reminders, they create a region around the location, for instance work, and register for region notifications.

While it might theoretically be possible to create lots of little regions next to each other, it's not really intended for that and will probably cause problems down the line.

Comment: can be done!! you can specify monitoring significant event while your app is in the background, when you register when moving to background, even though your app is killed your app kill once again come to the background where you have to create the cllocation manager based on the key you get in the application did finish launching with options, then you will get updates. this way you can do things, you can process things in the background using dispatch_async task kindly see apple documentation for this

Answer (score 0):

In my testing I have observed that the region monitoring is sometimes not very accurate, i.e If I drive past a region I might not get any indication of having entered or exited the region. (under the hood it might be using something similar to significant location change)

Also the desiredAccuracy here is really the buffer (in meters) around the region where notifications should not be generated , this is to prevent multiple notifications if you are at the edge of a region.